# Recommended screenshot size for sourceforge

Tags: sourceforge

What size for Sourceforge project screenshots recommended?

I take several as original size 600*300px, but it's cropped at project page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked mine, 456 x 160 and 656 x 425 both are cropped on the front screen.
However once you click on them they display properly.

Comment: So you think there is no standard size?

Comment: I cannot find it documented on their site and there doesn't appear to be a limit.